# how do i get my edit mode view to ignore the solidify modifier and get the 2d framework/vertices?

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, vertices, solidify-modifier

[image: this is the view when i switch to edit mode, but i want the 2d framework shown in the second pic]

[image: this is how i want it to look in edit mode]
i was trying to make the donut but my edit mode is showing the 3d framework whereas i need the 2d framework for less complications.